# Extend the list of SE sites presented when a question is being closed as off-topic

Tags: feature-request

Actually, the only listed site is meta.english.stackexchange.com.
Is it possible to add other SE sites as well? Would not, for example, [Writers](https://writers.stackexchange.com/) and [English Language Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com/) suit in that list?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Writers is still in beta. Migration paths are usually only added to graduated sites. For example, there was no migration path from StackOverflow to Programmers until the latter went out of beta, even though many, many people wanted to have one right away. See e.g. [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64948/should-we-have-migrate-to-programmers-stackexchange-com-when-closing-a-question) and check the top answer by Shog9:

> [A site being in beta] means two thing[s]:
>
> 1. It may well be killed off. In which case, questions migrated there would be lost. Not that that's necessarily a bad thing...
> 2. It isn't fully defined yet. So it wouldn't necessarily be clear *which* questions were appropriate for migration.

That being <s>said</s> quoted, I would support migrating certain questions to Writers *manually*. (Easy to say, I know, as I wouldn't be the one in charge of actually doing it.) I have commented to that extent just two days ago, after [Jeff Atwood mentioned](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/593/closing-questions-about-how-to-improve-writing/594#594) that "quite frankly, [Writers] desperately needs our help to survive". Looking at the [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1623/writers) stats, I can see what he's talking about, and I am all for helping them out. In fact, they are struggling with the same metrics we used to struggle with ([number of questions](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/370/congratulations-1000-questions-in-74-days) and [visits per day](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/377/82-days-in-beta-visits-day-worrying/)), so I totally feel their pain.

On a more general note, see this related question by Eldros: [On Migrating and Dispatching: redirecting off-topic question from and to EL&U](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/462/on-migrating-and-dispatching-redirecting-off-topic-question-from-and-to-elu).

---

**Update April 15th 2011:** a migration path to Writers has been added.

[image: Migration paths]

Please put it to good use. By which I mean,

1. don't just vote to close, but vote to migrate questions that would be a good fit for Writers **and**
2. don't just vote to migrate, but vote to close obvious rubbish that doesn't belong anywhere.

Comment: So. Why are migration paths only added to sites out of beta?

Comment: @Carl Brannen That is because a beta site can still be closed, if it doesn't meet some requirements. Taking as example _Drupal Answers_, you will notice that [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/2978/drupal-answers) reports those requirements, and which values the site must reach.

Comment: @kiamlaluno; Perhaps I'm quite stupid, but it seems that this would be a reason to not migrate a problem TO a beta site; I don't see the reason to not allow migration OUT of a beta site. Hmmmmm.

Comment: @Carl: Ah, so that's what you're asking about. Well, moderators of any site (beta or not) can migrate questions to any other site (beta or not).